# What is a good starting point for a media streaming?

Tags: video-streaming

If you want to write an media streaming Application, which libraries or frameworks are good to start with?

**Edit:** I personaly program in C/C++, java and python but I appreciate every kind of answer.
Maybe this thread could be a starting for new programmers.

Comment: Do you care which languages you work with? And music, video, or both?

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.live555.com/ - it works really well. I am currently using it.